# Setting min/max on map view while Zooming Out using CartoType

Tags: openstreetmap, c#

I am working with the .NET CartoType SDK on Windows.

How can I set a limitation on Zoom Out?

In the "Windows Maps" app I am able to Zoom Out to a very little map size.

[image: Zoom Out]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now use the function SetViewLimits:

```
Result CartoType.Framework.SetViewLimits(double aMinScaleDenominator,double aMaxScaleDenominator,Geometry aPanArea)
```

Zooming is restricted to the range between aMinScaleDenominator and aMaxScaleDenominator, and panning is restricted so that the edges of the display always touch the bounds of aPanArea.

Use the value zero to remove either or both of the two zoom limits. Use an empty (not null) geometry object to remove panning limits. Use a null geometry object to limit panning to the extent of the map.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the function SetViewLimits:

```
Result CartoType.Framework.SetViewLimits(double aMinScaleDenominator,double aMaxScaleDenominator,Geometry aPanArea)
```

Zooming is restricted to the range between aMinScaleDenominator and aMaxScaleDenominator, and panning is restricted so that the edges of the display always touch the bounds of aPanArea.

Use the value zero to remove either or both of the two zoom limits. Use an empty (not null) geometry object to remove panning limits. **Use a null geometry object to limit panning to the extent of the map.**

To solve the problem given here, use the C# statement:

```
SetViewLimits(0,0,null);
```